# How to add method to Groovy List interface from Java?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm calling a Groovy script from my Java code and I figured out how to call a Java method from that script.

Now, inside the Java method I would like to add a method to List objects in that script, if possible in a way so that other invocations of Groovy scripts are not affected by this.
Access to `GroovyShell` and the related infrastructure is given.

Example script

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3]

javaMethodToInitializeSomeStuff()

myList.doTheWeirdestThings()
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this. I am trying to accomplish the exact same thing

Comment: @Hilikus kind of, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

My main target was to limit the visibility of my extension methods. I achieved this with `GrovyCategorySupport`.

The groovy code would look like this

```
def myList = [1, 2, 3]
withWeirdThings {
    myList.doTheWeirdestThings()
}
```

Inside `withWeirdThings`, I call [`GrovyCategorySupport.use`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/GroovyCategorySupport.html#use(java.util.List,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) with a list of the classes that provide extension methods (eg, one that defines `public static void doTheWeirdestThings(List<?> list)`) and the closure.

Answer (score -1):

I think unless you use a different class loader any changes you make to a class will apply to all instances in the JVM.

To add a method to the List class, where delegate is the list of items and collect'ing the list will create a new list returned from method double

```
List.metaClass.double << {
    delegate = delegate.collect { it *= 2 }
}
List items = [1, 2, 3]
items = items.double()
println items // [2, 4, 6]
```

The above won't change the actual items in the array but will return a new list.

Is there a reason you need to add a method to List rather than just doing something like:

```
items = items.collect { it * 2 }
println items // [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code you posted is Groovy, I'm looking for something equivalent for Java.

Comment: Its not an easy task to add methods to classes at runtime in Java. Also how would you call the added method (via reflection?). Why not just do the work in a second groovy class and call that from the script? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to invoke the extension method from Groovy, only the declaration of the method is in Java.